# On Ubuntu, how to install pygtk for python 2.7 through apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu, pygtk, apt-get, python-2.7

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10, which comes with Python 2.6.  I would like to test a PyGTK app I'm writing with Python 2.7.

After installing the `python2.7` package, if I try to run my app like this:
`python2.7 <my_app>`, I get the error:
`ImportError: No module named pygtk`

My first idea was to try uninstalling the `python-gtk2` package, then reinstalling it, in hopes that it would be installed for both Python versions this time around.

However, uninstalling that package would remove dozens of critical applications that depend on PyGTK, including `gnome-panel`.

Is there an `apt-get` command that will install PyGTK2 for Python 2.7 without first uninstalling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version that will work for you is [in 11.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/python-apt) (depends on **`python2.7`**). The one [in 10.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick-updates/python-apt) won't work since it depends on **`python2.6`** (and built against it).